# Is it common for someones questions to be 'targeted' for down votes?

Tags: discussion

It seems that I have angered someone who is running down my questions, all of which have numerous positive votes, and down voting each in turn. Is this a common or regular occurrence?

"...To the last, I grapple with thee; from hell's heart, I stab at thee; for hate's sake, I spit my last breath at thee."

Comment: Not regular in terms of what people publically complained about, but I know at least 4 people other than you to whom this has been happening and who went on record (2 of which it happened as late as today). Tango, Slytherincess, and Sachin (who just got 3 DVs today only one of which is on a poor post) and myself (my user profile has a link to a blog that logs the recent cases... most involving older posts that can only be "discovered" plausibly by visiting my profile)

Comment: @DVK I was assuming a relative 'newbe' with an attitude. The old timers and big dogs here seem pretty straight forward and instead of drive-by down voting, will usually explain and nudge what they see as an 'errant' question so that it can be rephrased and brought into the accepted protocol.

Comment: There are plenty of old timers who downvote a lot. Some with no comments. I am sure newbies with attitude happen as well; but those usually don't have enough clue to space out their revenge downvotes and get vote-reversed by serial voting script.

Comment: So those old timers would be the 'gatekeepers'?

Comment: I have different term for people (any-timers) who downvote decent questions for no reason with no explanation in bulk... but I'd rather avoid expressing it to avoid being suspended. Besides, Alfred said it better than I ever could. "Some people just like watching the world burn".

Comment: I hear what you're saying. I have a couple of those 'in real life'. A real joy to be around.

Comment: I just checked my voting record; In the time I've been here, just over a year, I've voted 1835 times and have never down-voted anyone.

Comment: @DVK has given you some good info.  Some of us he mentioned are in chat quite a bit and have gotten to know each other and some of us are in touch offline.  Since that's a small "core" group, most of whom have been here since soon after the start of SF.SE, I'm sure it's happened to others who either don't watch their stats or haven't complained publicly.  And, since I'm not here nearly as much as I used to be, it could have also happened to me in the past 6-12 months without me even noticing it.

Comment: While anyone will downvote, I don't think you'll see anyone systematically going through a profile and downvoting that person in particular unless it's a newbie or just a very immature person who's probably irritated many of us.  I don't serial downvote, but if I did, it'd be on someone who's particularly obnoxious or weak or who just doesn't get the site concept.  Usually, though, such people are so frustrated they don't stay long.

Comment: What I find interesting is that I wouldn't think you'd be a target for such an action until you had something like 10k rep or more - unless you've been active a lot recently and someone irrationally hates you.  But consider yourself in good company.  Some the people @DVK mentioned were quite active in helping this site get going and in helping shape it, so if you're as disliked as the rest of us in that group, we welcome you and say you should be proud that your writing has touched someone so much that they have to react so strongly.

Comment: Thanks guys, guess I'm in good company. To paraphrase Merlin; I'm a dream to some... A nightmare to others! lol

Comment: @Morgan, feel free to join us in chat sometime.  Many of us mentioned are there and, while I'm not always there, I can be pinged and sometimes will here that.

Comment: @Tango-So you guys let riffraff into the chat area?

Comment: @Morgan - We *are* riffraff ;) If it helps, I once got serially upvoted, which was very odd. Go figure. Do I think I've been serially downvoted before? I do think so, yes. When it was at its peak, I did seek help from the mods and they did look into it. I don't know if they indeed found an offender or if it was coincidental, but what appeared to me to be someone serial downvoting me did stop. I don't monitor my votes received very often, so I'm not sure what my current status is. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess Are you the sort that gives that sort a bad name?

Comment: @Slytherincess - speak for yourself. \*\*I\*\* don't chat all day about *Glee*. <g>

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if I'm the only user on the site who hasn't been serially downvoted....  Although I suspect posting that might put an end to my streak :P

Comment: @Beofett - All it takes is that one special post and you too can earn your own serial stalker.

Comment: @Morgan I'll have to point out that you're talking to the person whose first question was essentially "why don't webs come out of Spiderman's butt?".  If that didn't do it, I don't know what would....

Comment: @Beofett-That's too funny :-)

Comment: This is a major issue with Gamification: http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/6820/4430

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had that happen to me.  That was a few years ago.  I don't know if things are different now, but there was no way for moderators to verify who it was doing that at the time.  I was pretty sure, but there's still nothing you can do about it.

At least that's the way it was.

Every now and then someone goes on a vendetta.  Unfortunately there's always a few childish people around who think that's just fine to do.

Comment: I wouldn't mind if I got targeted in an up-vote vendetta I guess. Hey, maybe you guys could up-vote all of my questions to make me feel better. lol. They all deserve up-votes anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys.

Answer (score 5):

You've asked 47 questions. Ignoring those that were immediately closed as duplicates or "opinion based", you've had at least one downvote on 13 of those questions, representing over a quarter.

From what I can tell there's no vendetta against you by a single user (almost none of them were "late downvotes", nor was there a specific pattern in the downvoting).

Unless you get a notification that a user has been suspended for serial downvoting your answers, my advice is just to suck it up and move on with your life.

Comment: For the record, I've not downvoted any of your questions but I have voted to close a couple of duplicates

Comment: Can you tell who downvotes? I don't know what privileges your high rank bestows. For the record, I have no problem with warranted downvotes, especially if an explanation note is attached. If I'm remiss or lacking in my posts such correction is valuable in learning to do better. What prompted the question is that I've seen a marked increase in 'drive-by' downvotes over the last week or so. Those same posts have been, I believe, fairly well written and well received based on the upvotes. I'm not nearly as prolific as you oldtimers so asked for input and advise concerning what to me was unusual.

Comment: I just threw in a little Melville for flavor.

Comment: @Morgan - Who are you calling an old-timer? I've only been here four months...

Comment: OMG! Four months old and over 25k rep.!!! Somebody needs to get a hobby.

Comment: @morgan - Hobbies are for the weak...

Comment: Looks like someone has decided upon a hobby: today  
-2  30 mins ago  downvote Were there any jails or some type of incarceration centers in Middle Earth or Tolkien's universe?;  
-2  28 mins ago  downvote In the Star Trek Universe, can a non-cloak capable ship hide within another ship's cloak?;  
-2  30 mins ago  downvote In the Transformers movies, what Air Force rank is U.S. Air Force Combat Controller Robert Epps suppose to be?

Comment: My hobbies usually result in some kind of trauma.

Comment: I'm now taking bets. If the pattern holds, sometime between around 18:00 and 01:00 I should be getting at least 1 downvote. Possibly several. Don't say anything to spoil it. Remember, observation alters behavior.

Comment: @morgan - If it helps you feel better, I'll downvote one of your questions now.

Comment: LOL. Wait until 17:59

Comment: @Morgan - What time zone are you in? I'll set an alarm... FYI: I've changed it to an upvote now since I'm being nice :-)

Comment: Two more, same tactic and time frame.

Comment: @morgan - eventually they'll fall foul of the automated checker.

Comment: -Pacific Standard Time (PST) = GMT-8
More snipes, same time frame. It's currently 9:22 PM here.

Answer (score 3):

Stackexchange actually has [a feature to protect people from serial downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting). When one user systematically downvotes all contributions of another user, the system will detect this and revert it after 24 hours. One time I was a victim of a serial downvote campaign on stackoverflow and the reversal-system worked flawlessly. So whoever initiated the campaign wasn't successful on two accounts.

1. my reputation didn't suffer and
2. To my knowledge I did not change whatever behavior of mine caused the outrage because I still have no idea for what reason they were hating me so much.

Comment: I understand 'the management' has anticipated and taken measures to combat such petty and childish tactics. I also understand that such petty people who would employ such childish tactics try to stay 'under the radar' so to speak.